# Pass javascript variable in jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<select id="selectmaterial" class="textbox" size="12" name="materials" style="width:250px" multiple>
                                                    <?php

                                                    if($materials!=null&&$materials!=""){

                                                        foreach ($materials->result() as $row){
                                                            ?>
                                                            <option value="<?php echo $row->code;?>"><?php echo $row->code."-".$row->name; ?></option>
                                                        <?php }}?>

                                                </select>
```

I have the following code where I'm trying to pass the value of "materialcode"

```
$('#selectmaterial').change(function() {

    var materialcode = $("#selectmaterial").val();
    alert(materialcode);
    $.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/materialreceive_control/fillMaterialDetails",{mycode:'RAW5436'}, function( data ) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('[id$=mcode]').val(data.mcode);
        $('[id$=mname]').val(data.mname);
        $('[id$=cost]').val(data.cost);

    });
});
```

the alert I have used in here shows the material code correctly, and when I pass the hard coded value like `{mycode:'RAW5436'}` it works fine, but when I replace the hard coded value with `{mycode:materialcode}` it doesn't give me anything. Is there anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Not enough information given. Inspect the actual request in network tab of browser console to see what actually gets sent, and what response from server is. Need to narrow down if problem is in javascript or at server. Also no need to search for the same element... can use `$(this).val()`

Comment: check any server side problem that avoid getting result.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectmaterial').change(function() {
    var materialcode = $("#selectmaterial").val();
    $.post( "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/materialreceive_control/fillMaterialDetails", {mycode: materialcode}, function( data ) {
        var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $('[id$=mcode]').val(data.mcode);
        $('[id$=mname]').val(data.mname);
        $('[id$=cost]').val(data.cost);
    });
});
```

Are you sure that data wasn't sended? Open F12 console, and check in NETWORK tabs what data was sended to the server. Use `console.log(materialcode);` to debug JS applications. We used alert() many years ago.  To view console.log open F12 console tab.

Comment: Ok it says Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' SELECT * FROM `rawmaterial` WHERE `code` = `Array`, and the data is showing inside that like ["RAW5436"]

Comment: I guess it's being sent as an array when I pass the variable itself

Comment: in php, you should create a dictionary with some keys and values. check all in server and send simple response to browser. you can set content-type as `application/json` in response header to get nice and fast result.(and then , not need to jQuery.parseJSON(data) in javascript !)

Comment: So your problem is not in JavaScript. Your problem is in PHP. Write print_r($_POST); in PHP, check how data was receiverd (check responce in f12), and then extract it to an variable in php. Then use that variable in SQL query.